# Upgrade multiple systems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have Linux Mint Petra 16 on two machines. I want to upgrade the to Qiana 17 (or Rebecca 17.1). The update process as I understand is, changing the source repo from Petra to Rebecca, and corresponding Ubuntu sources. 
Doing this on both machines would require me to download the packages twice. Is there a way to download the packages only once for both machines and have one machine upgrade using other's help? (Tags linux and ubuntu because I'm guessing that if there is a way, it would be similar for ubuntu too)

Answer (score 3):

I was responsible for three Ubuntu servers and half a dozen Ubuntu clients in my previous job. We used Puppet for managing mass updates and upgrades, among other things. It is a complex piece of software that takes quite a bit of learning -- they even have official courses and certification exams for administrators, so I would not recommend it unless you are an inquisitive type of user.

If you only have a couple of computers, I recommend a much simpler approach: simply perform the upgrade procedure on one computer, then copy all the downloaded packages (*.deb files) in `/var/cache/apt/archives` from that computer to the second one. Then, repeat the upgrade procedure (including updating the package database) on the second computer. The package manager will *not* download packages that already exist in that directory. Both computers must be running the same version and architecture variant of Ubuntu/Mint for this to work, i.e. either x86 on both computers or x86-64 on both computers.

To avoid having to manually copy the files in /var/cache/apt/archives, you can share that directory using NFS or Samba on one computer and mount it on the other, but that is beyond the scope of your question.